# As a server admin, how do I change the decay rate in Rust?

Tags: rust

I can see that there's a decay rate server variable [here](http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Server_Commands), but I can't find anywhere on the internet how the values work. Will 0 disable it? How do I make it really slow? or really fast? Can I just change the value and then run the `save.all` command?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a new feature (I only recently started playing) but entering the command `decay.scale 0` into the admin console disabled decay for me. I've been playing on a personal private server for weeks with zero decay.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running [Oxide](http://oxidemod.org) on the Server you might use the rather popular plugin [NoDecay](http://oxidemod.org/plugins/nodecay.1160/), which allows to disable decay completely as well as various options to tweak decay settings as desired.

Answer (score -1):

Enter this into console: 
`decay.decaytickrate 0.000001`

Comment: Can you explain what this does exactly? It seems like it might slow decay down considerably, but more detail should be given.

Comment: Do not set it to values below 0, according to [this link](https://forums.multiplay.com/rust/98372-unable-set-decay-decaytickrate-0-000001)